# Why the metaclass definition changed the mro of classic class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, method-resolution-order

According to [Method Resolution Order](http://python-history.blogspot.tw/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html):

> Classic classes used a simple MRO scheme: when looking up a method,
>   base classes were searched using a simple depth-first left-to-right
>   scheme.

This can be verified in Python 2.6

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.version
Out[2]: '2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56) \n[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)]'

In [3]: 
class D:
    def f(self): return 'D'
class B(D): pass
class C(D):
    def f(self): return 'C'
class A(B, C): pass
   ...: 

In [4]: A().f()
Out[4]: 'D'
```

However, I got a different result in Python 2.7.12 if I have defined a metaclass:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: class D:       # Note: Old-style
   ...:     def f(self): return "D.f()"
   ...: class B(D): pass
   ...: class C(D):
   ...:     def f(self): return "C.f()"
   ...: class A(B, C): pass
   ...: 

In [2]: A().f()
Out[2]: 'D.f()'    # It works as expected.

In [3]: class __metaclass__(type):
   ...:     "All classes are metamagically modified to be nicely printed"
   ...:     __repr__ = lambda cls: cls.__name__
   ...:     

In [4]: class D:       # Note: Old-style
   ...:     def f(self): return "D.f()"
   ...: class B(D): pass
   ...: class C(D):
   ...:     def f(self): return "C.f()"
   ...: class A(B, C): pass
   ...: 

In [5]: A().f()
Out[5]: 'C.f()'   # WTF??
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your 2.7 behavior on any of `2.7.14 [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)]` (Mac OSX), `2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08) \n[GCC 6.3.0 20170118]` (Debian 9.0), or `2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]` (Ubuntu 16.04, which looks like the exact same version you're running). The result is always `D.f()`. Only when I use new-style classes do they report `C.f()`.

Comment: @birryree Sorry for mine misleading question. I have found that my result due to a previous definition of metaclass. And I have modified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metaclasses only apply to new-style classes, and are added by having a field named `__metaclass__` in the class body. Having a `__metaclass__` field causes the class to be a new-style class whether you inherit from `object` or not:

```
class J:
  pass
class K(object):
  pass
class L:
  __metaclass__ = type

type(J) # <type 'classobj'>
type(K) # <type 'type'>
type(L) # <type 'type'>
```

So what's happening in your example appears to be that due to lexical/static scoping rules, your metaclass named `__metaclass__` is in scope when the body of class `D` is executed the second time. Since Python  sees a `__metaclass__` in scope when the body is executed, it uses that as the metaclass for `D` and turns it into a new-style class, which changes the method resolution order.

---

You probably shouldn't be naming a metaclass `__metaclass__`. Name it something descriptive like `PrettyPrintClassRepr` and apply it to classes when you want it by using `__metaclass__ = PrettyPrintClassRepr` in the class body:

```
class D:
  __metaclass__ = PrettyPrintClassRepr
```